# Why useAsync is not get called when state change?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous

I'm trying to make an api call using useAsync from `react-use` and it's working in the first time, but when the state changes, useAsync is not executed again.

```
export const MyComponent = () => {
  const [appTaskList, setAppTaskList] = React.useState('');
  const [envTaskList, setEnvTaskList] = React.useState('');
  const [loadTaskList, setLoadTaskList] = React.useState(false);

  console.log({appTaskList});

  return (
    <Page themeId="tool">
      <Content>
        <Grid container spacing={2} direction="column">
          <Grid item>
          <TaskContext.Provider value={{ appTaskList, setAppTaskList, envTaskList, setEnvTaskList, loadTaskList, setLoadTaskList }}>
            <FetchEnvsComponent />
          </TaskContext.Provider>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            {
              loadTaskList ? (
                <TaskComponent app={appTaskList} env={envTaskList}/>
              ) : null
            }
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Content>
    </Page>
  )
};
```

So, every time `appTaskList` and `envTaskList` change, the TaskComponent component is rendered again. This is the component:

```
export const TaskComponent = ({ app, env }) => {
  const { fetch } = useApi(fetchApiRef);
  const config = useApi(configApiRef);
  const backendUrl = config.getString('backend.baseUrl');
  const apiPath = config.get('aws.path');
  const query = getQuery(useEntity().entity, env, app);

  const { value, loading, error } = useAsync(async (): Promise<any[]> => {
    const response = await fetch(`${backendUrl}${apiPath}/tasks?${query}`);
    console.log("useAync execution")
    return await response.json();
  }, []);

  const columns: TableColumn[] = parseTableData(value);

  if (loading) {
    return <Progress />;
  } else if (error) {
    return <ResponseErrorPanel error={error} />;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Table
        options={{ paging: false, padding: 'dense' }}
        data={testData10}
        columns={columns}
        title={`${app} ${env} task definitions`}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I can only see the `console.log("useAync execution")` once. What am I missing here? How to execute this api call every time `appTaskList` and `envTaskList` change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the app and env props to the useAsync dependency array

```js
const { value, loading, error } = useAsync(async (): Promise<any[]> => {
    const response = await fetch(`${backendUrl}${apiPath}/tasks?${query}`);
    console.log("useAync execution")
    return await response.json();
  }, [app, env]); // <-- added props to dependency array
```